# How to add an Enum with python into a Ghidra project

Tags: python, ghidra

Saw someone using `ghidra.app.util.cparser.C` to parse a string of a struct into a struct object and than they added it into Ghidra using `data_type_manager.addDataType()`. I want to implement that method with Enumerates but I'm not sure how.
If there is a better method to add an Enum I will gladly use it, and if this is the best way to do it an explanation would be a great help.
here is my reference: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23330/ghidra-python-create-struct-with-big-endian-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an enum via the CParser and then add the resulting DataType to the DataTypeManager. I have a [script for this generic workflow](https://github.com/fmagin/ghidra_scripts/blob/master/ParseDataType.java), if you don't care about scripting it yourself, and are content with a simple GUI to paste C code into, check the resulting DataType and add it if desired.

Otherwise you can also create an enum data type directly:

```py
from ghidra.program.model.data import EnumDataType
# maximum enum value is (2^length)-1 according to some comment, but if you pass 8 it should be every possible Java long value, so I am not sure
enum = EnumDataType("EnumName", length)
enum.add("One", 1)
enum.add("Two", 2)
enum.add("Three", 3)
dataTypeManager.addDataType(enum, None)
```

Comment: I noticed that there is no contractor in the BitFieldDataType class.
Is there a way to use this method for a bitfield?

Comment: Can BitFields ever appear outside of a struct? `StructureDataType` has a public method `insertBitFieldAt` which might be the intended way to create one. In my experience most of the time there is no public constructor available, there is a reason for it and there is some other method you are supposed to use to create it.